# why there need add '!' in code suffix

Tags: swift

```
enum Season: Int {
    case Spring = 0
    case Summer = 1
    case Autumn = 2
    case Winter = 3
}

var SeasonTime1 = Season.Spring

//why ？ this code suffix need add ！
SeasonTime1 = Season.init(rawValue: 2)!
```

1. List item
   // why? there don't need add !
   var SeasonTime2 = Season.init(rawValue: 2)

Comment: Leave it off and look at the compiler error. It will tell you that `init` might have failed, and you have to handle it somehow (for example by `!`, but that is not the only option)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because Enum uses a failable initializer (see documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Declarations.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH34-ID376)). As its title implies, a failable initilizer can fail and return nil. Objects that can contain nil are Optionals in Swift. Therefore you could have:

```
let seasonTime1 = Season.init(rawValue: 2)
```

In which case the type of seasonTime1 is `Optional<Season>`. When you want to use the value, you then have to unwrap the Optional, either using `if let`, `guard` or `!`. In this case:

```
let seasonTime1 = Season.init(rawValue: 2)!
```

You're unwrapping it immediately, so the type of seasonTime1 will be `Season`. Note the following code:

```
let seasonTime1 = Season.init(rawValue: 2222)!
```

This will run, but if you access seasonTime1 it will fail. This is because there is no enum with a raw value of 2222, and so seasonTime1 will contain nil. Since it is implicitly unwrapped, the fact that it contains nil is illegal, which will cause a crash if the unwrapping occurs.

Comment: Thanks your answer !

Answer (score 0):

Because the compiler cannot infer that the raw value type exists so you need the '!' too force unwrap it. If you wrap it in a guard statement you can ensure that it is of the type that "you" know it is. Then you don't need the '!'

Comment: Thanks your answer !